# unable to activate virtualenv venv in windows 7

Tags: python, virtualenv

[image: screenshot -> activating venv]

When I go to venv/Scripts/activate.bat and hit enter, nothing happens.
Please refer screenshot

Comment: have you tried creating the virtual env using `venv` instead of `Virtualenv`? It's `python -m venv [path/to/venv]`. The docs- https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is supposed to be printed when you activate your virtualenv. Chances are that your virtual environment is activated.

Answer (score 0):

You can test this by running:

```
pip -V
```

If you are running inside of a `vnev`, it will then show a path to the `vnev`'s location.

Example output when not running in a `vnev`:

```
pip 20.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

And example output when running in a `vnev`:

```
pip 20.1 from /Users/USER/DIRECTORY/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```